# Upgrade PHP version from 7.2.13 to 7.2.15 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, php, amazon-ec2

I want to upgrade the PHP version in my Ubuntu instance.

I run below commands.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
```

[image]

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

[image]

Then I run;

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2.15
```

But it gaves me an error.

[image]

So I run below.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

[image]

Finally run below.

```
$ php -v
```

[image]

But it still shows as 7.2.13.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get version 7.2.15 this way because the ppa does not provide this version.
See [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=php7&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=).

From a quick google search, I cannot find anybody providing the exact version prebuilt.

You can always get the exact version you want by compiling from [source](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/php-7.2.15).
This will take some skill and time. You will also need to manually swap the version apache or nginx is running with. You will need to restart your web server at the end.

You might find [this article](https://docs.moodle.org/37/en/Compiling_PHP_from_source) helpful - didn't try personally, and [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/archive/php-7.2.15.zip) is the link to the source code.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get 7.2.15 instead of 7.2.19?

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use that particular version instead of a newer one?

Comment: I have a WordPress site. At the moment, it is running on 7.2.13. But I want to upgrade it to 7.2.15 as per a client requirement.

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita That "client requirement" doesn't make sense.